# WPF modal progress window

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, window, modal-dialog

I apologize if this question has been answered tons of times, but I can't seem to find an answer that works for me.  I would like to create a modal window that shows various progress messages while my application performs long running tasks.  These tasks are run on a separate thread and I am able to update the text on the progress window at different stages of the process.  The cross-thread communication is all working nicely.  The problem is that I can't get the window to be on top of only other application windows (not every application on the computer), stay on top, prevent interaction with the parent window, and still allow the work to continue.

Here's what I've tried so far:

First, my splash window is a custom class that extends the Window class and has methods to update the message box.  I create a new instance of the splash class early on and Show/Hide it as needed.

In the simplest of cases, I instantiate the window and call `.Show()` on it:

```
//from inside my secondary thread
this._splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this._splash.Show());

//Do things
//update splash text
//Do more things

//close the splash when done
this._splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this._splash.Hide());
```

This correctly displays the window and continues running my code to handle the initialization tasks, but it allows me to click on the parent window and bring that to the front.

Next I tried disabling the main window and re-enabling later:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false));

//show splash, do things, etc

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.MainWindow.IsEnabled = true));
```

This disables all the elements in the window, but I can still click the main window and bring it in front of the splash screen, which is not what I want.

Next I tried using the topmost property on the splash window.  This keeps it in front of everything, and in conjunction with setting the main window IsEnabled property I could prevent interaction, but this makes the splash screen appear in front of EVERYTHING, including other applications.  I don't want that either.  I just want it to be the topmost window within THIS application.

Then I found posts about using `.ShowDialog()` instead of `.Show()`.  I tried this, and it correctly showed the dialog and did not allow me to click on the parent window, but calling `.ShowDialog()` makes the program hang waiting for you to close the dialog before it will continue running code.  This is obviously, not what I want either.  I suppose I could call `ShowDialog()` on a different thread so that that thread would hang but the thread doing the work would not...is that the recommended method?

I have also considered the possibility of not using a window at all and instead putting a full-sized window element in front of everything else on the page.  This would work except that I have other windows I open and I'd like to be able to use the splash screen when those are open too.  If I used a window element I would have to re-create it on every window and I wouldn't be able to use my handy `UpdateSplashText` method in my custom splash class.

So this brings me to the question.  What is the right way to handle this?

Thanks for your time and sorry for the long question but details are important :)

Answer (score 22):

You are correct that `ShowDialog` gives you most of the UI behavior that you want.

It does have the problem that as soon as you call it you block execution though.  How could you possibly run some code after you show the form, but define what it should be before it's shown?  That's your problem.

You could just do all of the work within the splash class, but that's rather poor practice due to tight coupling.

What you can do is leverage the `Loaded` event of `Window` to define code that should run after the window is shown, but where it is defined before you show it.

```
public static void DoWorkWithModal(Action<IProgress<string>> work)
{
    SplashWindow splash = new SplashWindow();

    splash.Loaded += (_, args) =>
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(
            data => splash.Text = data);

        worker.DoWork += (s, workerArgs) => work(progress);

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
            (s, workerArgs) => splash.Close();

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    };

    splash.ShowDialog();
}
```

Note that this method is designed to encapsulate the boilerplate code here, so that you can pass in any worker method that accepts the progress indicator and it will do that work in a background thread while showing a generic splash screen that has progress indicated from the worker.

This could then be called something like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    DoWorkWithModal(progress =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);//placeholder for real work;
        progress.Report("Finished First Task");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);//placeholder for real work;
        progress.Report("Finished Second Task");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);//placeholder for real work;
        progress.Report("Finished Third Task");
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 but note you could make a function `void Foo(Action<Action<int, string>> work)` that encapsulates all the non-task-specific stuff, so that it could be reused for various tasks, where you set `worker.DoWork += delegate { work(worker.ReportProgress); };`.  That way it's both decoupled and reusable.

Comment: @DaxFohl If I was going to go that far I'd probably pass around an `IProgress<string>` object instead of an `Action<int, string>`; it would help carry the semantics better.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it looks like a great option. I'll have to try it out some day.  For now, since my solution is working, I'll go with that so I can stay only marginally behind schedule.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Helped me alot. I've added another answer below with an `async` and **MVVM** approach.

Comment: @MarcusKaseder What exactly breaks the MVVM approach in this example?

Comment: @request The missing ViewModel

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer from @Servy helped me a lot! And I wanted to share my Version with the `async` and MVVM approach. It also contains a small delay to avoid "window flickering" for too fast operations.

**Dialog Method:**

```
public static async void ShowModal(Func<IProgress<string>, Task> workAsync, string title = null, TimeSpan? waitTimeDialogShow = null)
{
    if (!waitTimeDialogShow.HasValue)
    {
        waitTimeDialogShow = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
    }

    var progressWindow = new ProgressWindow();
    progressWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;

    var viewModel = progressWindow.DataContext as ProgressWindowViewModel;
    Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(text => viewModel.Text = text);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        viewModel.Title = title;
    }

    var workingTask = workAsync(progress);

    progressWindow.Loaded += async (s, e) =>
    {
        await workingTask;

        progressWindow.Close();
    };

    await Task.Delay((int)waitTimeDialogShow.Value.TotalMilliseconds);

    if (!workingTask.IsCompleted && !workingTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        progressWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    ShowModal(async progress =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); // Task 1
        progress.Report("Finished first task");

        await Task.Delay(5000); // Task 2
        progress.Report("Finished second task");
    });
```

Thanks again @Servy, saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your progress window's constructor take a `Task` and then ensure the window calls `task.Start` on the `OnLoaded` event.  Then you use `ShowDialog` from the parent form, which will cause the progress window to start the task.

Note you could also call `task.Start` in the constructor, or in the parent form anywhere before calling `ShowDialog`.  Whichever makes most sense to you.

Another option would be just to use a progress bar in the status strip of the main window, and get rid of the popup.  This option seems to be more and more common these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Visibility` property on `Window` to hide the whole window while the splash screen runs.

XAML

```
<Window ... Name="window" />
```

Code

```
window.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

//show splash 
//do work
//end splash

window.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: I didn't want to hide I just wanted it "disabled" while the dialog is up.  The modality created by calling "ShowDialog" is perfect, but I needed it to not halt execution.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to make this work by calling `ShowDialog()` on a separate thread.  I created my own `ShowMe()` and `HideMe()` methods in my dialog class that handle the work.  I also capture the `Closing` event to prevent closing the dialog so I can re-use it.

Here's my code for my splash screen class:

```
public partial class StartupSplash : Window
{
    private Thread _showHideThread;

    public StartupSplash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Closing += OnCloseDialog;
    }


    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lb_progress.Content.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
                this.lb_progress.Content = value;
            else
                this.lb_progress.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.lb_progress.Content = value));
        }
    }


    public void ShowMe()
    {
        _showHideThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(doShowHideDialog));
        _showHideThread.Start(true);
    }

    public void HideMe()
    {
        //_showHideThread.Start(false);
        this.doShowHideDialog(false);
    }

    private void doShowHideDialog(object param)
    {
        bool show = (bool)param;

        if (show)
        {
            if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
                this.ShowDialog();
            else
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.ShowDialog()));
        }
        else
        {
            if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
                this.Close();
            else
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Close()));
        }
    }


    private void OnCloseDialog(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work but you'll probably run into fewer problems in the long run if all your UI controls are all on the same thread.

Comment: Multiple UI threads is *really* hard to work with, and can cause a lot of subtle and hard to understand or work around problems due to underlying assumptions made throughout the existing UI frameworks that there is only one UI thread.

Comment: I would normally agree that having multiple UI threads is complicated, but in this case, the SplashScreen encapsulates all of the secondary thread logic right inside.  All I have to do is call ShowMe and set the Message property to alter the text on the dialog.  The caller doesn't have to be aware of the extra threads.  It's very easy to work with and I think it'll do just fine.  I'll certainly investigate the other answers here, but for now I have to move on as my deadline was last week :(

Comment: does this cover everything i think you can still reach your "Main" window through the tray, it isn't blocked.