# ShowDialog() while doing some actions

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, window

I am working on a Window to show the currently performing task on my MainWindow.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
Window progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
using(progressDialog .ShowDialog())
{
    //Perform some tasks and Update UI on progressDialog

} // Close/Dispose the progressdialog by itself
```

Obviously `ShowDialog()` blocks the execution so I cannot do sth. on the MainWindow while the other is shwon.

Things I definedly need:

1. Display that/any `Dialog` as a real dialog (**just `TopMost` is no option**)

   - I want to prevent the user to do sth. while loading
2. `using` would be super nice since its easy to use and wrapp around long running tasks

**EDIT:**

Details on what I thought of:

1. User Hits "Refresh"
2. New "Status/Progreess-Update" is created
3. Passing StatusUpdate to ProgressWindow(orange) (if possible we get that window from `using`)
4. If there is an active Instance of ProgressWindow add the StatusUpdate to its Collection - otherwise show new Window
5. At the EndOfUsing CloseWindow()

For example "Refresh" can contain the following actions:

1. Connect to database
2. Query data
3. Display data

I would like to have an entry for each of those on my progress-window.

[image]

Is this possible ? - I'm open for alternatives :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF modal progress window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258006/wpf-modal-progress-window)

Comment: Why don't you start the task before you call the ShowDialog method?

Comment: Lets say my progress window contains a ListView showing progressbars for each task. Once 1 finishes I want to start the next one, update the window and add it to my ListView. ShowDialog() will block my from starting another task

Comment: This is not a duplicate. @Felix D. is specifically asking whether this can be done with `using` pattern with calculations on the UI thread (unlike in the question linked, which asks for a general guidance on progress window)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in production application. This can be done in following way:

1. Create your own `IDisposable` progress window wrapper
2. In your wrapper's constructor spin up a new `STA` thread and from that thread create and show (using `Show()`, not `ShowDialog()`) your progress window with `Topmost` property set to `true`. Remember to call `Dispatcher.Run()` on this thread after `Show`-ing your window.
3. Update any data in your progress window through `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` calls
4. In your wrapper's `Dispose` method, close the window and shut down the thread.

**EDIT**: Disabling main window can be done using `Win32` api `EnableWindow`:

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool bEnable);


    public static void DisableWindow(Window window)
    {
        EnableWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle(), false);

    }

    public static void EnableWindow(Window window)
    {
        EnableWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle(), true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Code for running window on another thread

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    window_ = new ProgressWindow();
    window_.Show();

    window_.Closed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        window_.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    };

    Dispatcher.Run();

});

thread.Name = "ProgressWindowThread";
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Closing can be done with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` with `window.Close()`.

Comment: This won't prevent the user from interacting with the actual window. Since it't no "real" dialog :/

Comment: Progress window should have only minimal interaction options (mostly cancel button) anyway.

Comment: Its not about the interaction with that window. I DONT want the user to do anything on the MAINWINDOW. Like press "Refresh" again while it's already refreshing => TopMost does not handle that.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say my progress window contains a `ListView` showing progressbars for each task. Once 1 finishes I want to start the next one, update the window and add it to my `ListView`. ShowDialog() will block my from starting another task.

Not if you start the task before you call the blocking `ShowDialog()` method. Below is a basic example for you.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" />
<Button Content="Show Dialog" Click="Button_Click_1" />
```

**Code:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //simulate some long-running work...
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lb.Items.Add("task x...")));
        }
    });
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window dialog = new Window();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

The task will continue to update the `ListBox` while the dialog is displayed.

Comment: Seems to a totally different question (much broader!) now. I don't really understand your issue. The window is updated as expected while the dialog is open in my example. What else do you want?